# Is there any difference between like best and like the best?

Tags: grammar

Is there a difference between these two sentences? Are they the same?

1. What color do you like ***the*** best?
2. What color do you like best?

Is there a difference in their meaning?

Comment: None I think, the former seems more formal though

Answer (score 1):

Some say that the usage of "the best" is ambiguous but has come to be accepted now. Technically, both are the same, with the usage of "the" sounding more informal and the lack of it being less grammatical(but not incorrect) in nature.
Here is the article I referred to:
https://jakubmarian.com/like-more-vs-like-better-like-the-most-vs-like-most-like-the-best-vs-like-best/

Comment: Thank you. I also found this in a forum: Of the all the sports, I like American football the most – In this context, you are making a a selection among many choice. 

One thing I like most about John is his honesty – In this context, you are particularly stating what you like.  https://www.englishforums.com/English/IMostBestBestMost/cgzwr/post.htm

Comment: What do you think about the above-mentioned point?